# {Unknown expression after the reported line} with mock

Tags: c++, ethereum, googlemock

I run a test with all my expected calls. The test reaches the end and then throw an error. I am making a test for the function engine*exchangeTransitionConfiguration. The test has to mock a cursor, dbreader (mock*_transaction) and db. It will reach the end of the test, since I place a std::cout at the bottom of the test case, and the std::cout does print. I been looking for the reason but can't find why.

```
TEST_CASE("handle_engine_transition_configuration_v1 succeeds if EL configurations has the same request configuration", "[silkrpc][engine_api]") { SILKRPC_LOG_VERBOSITY(LogLevel::None); silkworm::Bytes chain_config_bytes{*silkworm::from_hex( "7b22636861696e4964223a313333373330322c22686f6d657374656164426c6f6" "36b223a302c22656970313530426c6f636b223a302c22656970313535426c6f63" "6b223a302c2262797a616e7469756d426c6f636b223a302c22636f6e7374616e7" "4696e6f706c65426c6f636b223a302c2270657465727362757267426c6f636b22" "3a302c22697374616e62756c426c6f636b223a302c226265726c696e426c6f636" "b223a302c226c6f6e646f6e426c6f636b223a302c227465726d696e616c546f74" "616c446966666963756c7479223a2231303030303030222c227465726d696e616" "c426c6f636b4e756d626572223a302c227465726d696e616c426c6f636b486173" "68223a22307833353539653835313437306636653762626564316462343734393" "83036383365386333313562666365393962326136656634376330353763303464" "6537383538227d")}; silkworm::Bytes key(8, '\0');

silkrpc::ContextPool context_pool{1, []() { return grpc::CreateChannel("localhost", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()); }};
auto context_pool_thread = std::thread([&]() { context_pool.run(); });

MockDatabase mock_database;
MockTransaction* mock_transaction = new MockTransaction();
MockCursor* mock_cursor_1 = new MockCursor();
MockCursor* mock_cursor_2 = new MockCursor();
std::unique_ptr<ethdb::Database> database_ptr{&mock_database};


EXPECT_CALL(mock_database, begin()).WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(
    [&]() -> asio::awaitable<std::unique_ptr<ethdb::Transaction>> {
        co_return std::unique_ptr<ethdb::Transaction>{mock_transaction};
    }
));

EXPECT_CALL(*mock_transaction, cursor(db::table::kCanonicalHashes)).WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(
    [&]() -> asio::awaitable<std::shared_ptr<ethdb::Cursor>> {
        co_return std::shared_ptr<ethdb::Cursor>{mock_cursor_1};
    }
));

EXPECT_CALL(*mock_cursor_1, seek_exact(testing::_)).WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(
    [&]() -> asio::awaitable<KeyValue> {
        co_return KeyValue{silkworm::Bytes{}, key};
    }
));

EXPECT_CALL(*mock_transaction, cursor(db::table::kConfig)).WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(
    [&]() -> asio::awaitable<std::shared_ptr<ethdb::Cursor>> {
        co_return std::shared_ptr<ethdb::Cursor>{mock_cursor_2};
    }
));


EXPECT_CALL(*mock_cursor_2, seek(testing::_)).WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(
    [&]() -> asio::awaitable<KeyValue> {
        co_return KeyValue{silkworm::Bytes{}, chain_config_bytes};
    }
));

nlohmann::json reply;
nlohmann::json request = R"({
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":1,
    "method":"engine_transitionConfigurationV1",
    "params": [{
        "terminalTotalDifficulty":"0xf4240",
        "terminalBlockHash":"0x3559e851470f6e7bbed1db474980683e8c315bfce99b2a6ef47c057c04de7858",
        "terminalBlockNumber":"0x0"
    }]
})"_json;
std::unique_ptr<ethbackend::BackEnd> backend_ptr;
EngineRpcApiTest rpc(database_ptr, backend_ptr);
auto result{asio::co_spawn(context_pool.get_io_context(), [&rpc, &reply, &request]() {
    return rpc.handle_engine_exchange_transition_configuration_v1(
        request,
        reply
    );
}, asio::use_future)};
result.get();

CHECK((reply == TransitionConfiguration{
    .terminal_total_difficulty = intx::from_string<intx::uint256>("1000000"),
    .terminal_block_hash = 0x3559e851470f6e7bbed1db474980683e8c315bfce99b2a6ef47c057c04de7858_bytes32,
    .terminal_block_number = 0
}));
context_pool.stop();
context_pool_thread.join();
}
```

this is the test

I expected a successful test, yet in response I got the following error.

`/Users/enriavil1/Desktop/projects/silkrpc/silkrpc/commands/engine_api_test.cpp:276: FAILED:   {Unknown expression after the reported line} due to a fatal error condition:   SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation signal`

Comment: This might be in an object destructor or in googletest library code for cleaning up the test case. Debugging the test program in a standard debugger should give more clues.